# Can the buyer's salesperson receive commission directly from a private seller?

Tags: canada, real-estate

Imagine a private seller wants to save money by not hiring an agent, but is willing to pay some amount to a potential buyer's agent to seal the deal.

In the described situation can the buyer's salesperson receive the commission directly or they should have the seller to write a cheque or something under the brokerage's name and then get their share from the brokerage after the brokerage has taken their portion?

Comment: Do real-estate transactions work differently in Canada than the US? In the US, a buyers agent commission is (almost always) paid by the seller.

Comment: @Ron Beyer  A buyer's real estate agent is thing both in Canada and the USA, apparently. Here's a random example from Wisconsin: https://buysellloveupnorthwi.com/buyers-guide/buyers-agent-vs-sellers-agent/

Comment: @RockApe Having bought and sold homes/land (and specifically in WI), I know that buyers and (usually) sellers have agents. I also know that in the two states I've bought real-estate in, the seller was the one who paid the commissions for both sides. Typically a buyers agent has a contract with the buyer for an amount (usually 2%), but it's paid by the seller. *The seller typically pays the buyers agent* so I'm not sure what the question is? Extra money over that commission? Or are they asking about paying the commission?

Comment: @Ron Beyer  I misread your comment, sorry!

Comment: @RonBeyer In Canada if the seller has a brokerage representing them, they would pay the commission to their brokerage and seller brokerage would give half of the money to the buyer's brokerage. After the buyer's brokerage receives half of the money they would based on their contract with the salesperson take some of the commission and give the rest to the buyer's agent. What I am asking is that in a situation where the seller isn't represented by a brokerage is it legal to get the money directly from the seller so that you don't have to pay your brokerage.